# Remove applied background color using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I applied background color to button as below:

```
$("input:button").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(2000).animate({backgroundColor: 'black',color:'#fff'});
});
```

On mouse over the color is applied properly. But how can I remove the same color on mouse out?

Comment: What do you mean by `stop(2000)`? `stop()` does not take such an argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code :

```
$("input:button").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(2000).css({backgroundColor: 'black',color:'#fff'});
}, function() {
    $(this).stop(2000).css({backgroundColor: '',color:''});
});
```

With the [hover method](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), the first function is executed on mouse enter and the second on mouse out. You can have a look to this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/lulu3030/tzR5m/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$("input:button").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop(2000).animate({backgroundColor: 'black',color:'#fff'});
},function(){
    $(this).stop(2000).animate({backgroundColor: '',color:'#000'});
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bzDPC/)

Answer (score 0):

Why this desperatly need to be a jquery function? Isn't the pure CSS way to do this more convenient ?